# Swift Gesture Recognizer That Tracks Only First Touch In Continuous Gesture

Tags: ios, swift, uigesturerecognizer, uipangesturerecognizer

I'm trying to use a gesture recognizer to allow the user to resize a view on the screen by dragging it with one finger... as such, I want to track all changes to the touch. I initially tried to use a `PanGestureRecognizer` for this, but I've run into an issue when the user touches the view with multiple fingers. I only want to track the first touch (ie the first finger the user places on the screen during a gesture), but I can't find a way to prevent additional touches from interfering with my ability to track the first. My initial solution was to simply set

```
recognizer.maximumNumberOfTouches = 1
```

However, this causes the entire gesture to be cancelled in the event of a second touch (I want to continue tracking the first touch in this case). But, of course, not setting this value to 1 causes the gesture to actually track multiple touches. **How can I make a gesture recognizer that tracks all changes to only the first touch in the gesture, and isn't cancelled by additional touches on the screen?**

Comment: What happen if you remove `recognizer.maximumNumberOfTouches = 1` this line?

Comment: With a standard PanGestureRecognizer, it tracks both touches. With my custom recognizer, it cancels the entire gesture (but seems to be slightly delayed in doing so).

Comment: Just get rid of that `touchesMoved` implementation.

Comment: @matt But after began if user touches his second finger in that case `touchBegan` will not call again.. isn't it?

Comment: Right but you don’t want it to. You want to just keep tracking the first finger, and that’s just what will happen

Comment: Getting rid of touchesMoved doesn't fix the issue; it just causes both fingers to be tracked again.

Comment: After doing some more digging, I think that the issue could be solved by overriding the `location(in:)` function in my custom gesture recognizer. If I override this to always return the location of only the first touch in the view, I think my problem will be solved. But, I'm not sure how to override this function.

Comment: @kmell96 In your question you mentioned that you want to continue tracking if second finger touch occurs in between right? So checking the number of touches at begging should work for you.

Comment: I was able to fix the issue by abandoning `PanGestureRecognizer` altogether and just subclassing `UIGestureRecognizer`, then overriding `touchesBegan`, `touchesMoved`, `touchesEnded`, and `location(in:)` to only notice the first touch registered by begin. The fix is probably too complicated and specific to my use cases to be useful to anyone else, but if anyone would like to see my solution, let me know and I can post it.

Comment: Sounds like you just misunderstand `location(in:)`. It does not apply to a single touch.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a UIGestureRecognizer subclass that will track all changes the first touch the user places on the screen at the start of a gesture, and will ignore all other fingers without cancelling the gesture. Note that if you're using functions/properties of the gesture recognizer (such as `location(in:)`), you'll probably have to override those as well.

```
class FirstTouchGestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer {
    private var firstTouch: UITouch? = nil

    override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent) {
        if firstTouch == nil {
            firstTouch = touches.first!
            self.state = .began
        }
    }

    override func touchesMoved(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent) {
        if firstTouch != nil && touches.contains(firstTouch!) {
            self.state = .changed
        }
    }

    override func touchesEnded(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent) {
        if firstTouch != nil && touches.contains(firstTouch!) {
            firstTouch = nil
            self.state = .ended
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

From your comments and answer, it sounds like your use of a pan gesture recognizer was always wrong and you were doing something wrong in your action handler. No correct action handler for a pan gesture recognizer would ever use `location(in:)` for anything. `location(in:)` gives you a centroid of all touches, which is exactly what you say you *don't* want — and in any case there is no need to consult it.

- If your goal is to drag a view, you use `translation(in:)`.
- If your goal is to track the actual location of a particular touch, you use `location(ofTouch:in:)`.
- If you discover that a touch is being delivered and you don't want it tracked, call `ignore(_:for:)`.

Comment: I think it's a little extreme to say that no action handler for a pan gesture would use `location(in:)` for anything; there are many uses of pan gestures and if it was truly incompatible with pans then it wouldn't be provided. You're correct that a pan was not the correct gesture for my use case (the recognizer I provided in my solution is correct), but none of your solutions would work because none of them prevent the gesture from being cancelled in the event of a secondary touch (and if I didn't set minimum number of touches, I can't know which touch to pass into `location(ofTouch:in:)`).

Comment: You might be right, but the problem here is that your question never showed what you wanted to do with this pan gesture recognizer (and still doesn't), so the issue you're having is not reproducible and your own answer doesn't answer anything in the question itself.

Comment: Ok, I'll edit my question to try to make it more clear, because I do think that somebody else with the same problem could benefit from my answer.